# Trouble accessing private members from my class header in my cpp file C++

Tags: c++, class, undefined

#### "Morg.h"

```
class Morg{
    public:
        void setName( std::string morgName );
        void setType( char morgType );
        void setXcoord( int xLocation );
        void setYcoord( int yLocation );
        void moveMorg( int currDirection );
        void consume( Morg morg );
        void reproduce( char morgType );
        void setBounds( int upperBound );
        void setDirection( int currDirection );
        char getType();

    private:
        std::string Name;
        char Type;
        int yCoord;
        int xCoord;
        int bounds;
        int direction;
};
```

#### "Morg.cpp"

```
#include "masterIncludes.h"
// The above has a bunch of std stuff like list and iostream ect.
#include "Morg.h"


void setName( std::string morgName ){
    Name = morgName; //I get an error here. it thinks `Name` is undefined.
                     //I've tried `Morg::Name` and it stays undefined.
                     // I dont know what im supposed to do.
}
std::string getName(){
    return Name;
}
void setType( char morgType ){}
void setXcoord( int xLocation ){}
void setYcoord( int yLocation ){}
void moveMorg( int currDirection ){}
void consume( Morg morg ){}
void reproduce( char morgType ){}
void setBounds( int upperBound ){}
void setDirection( int currDirection ){}
char getType(){}
```

I get errors when trying to get and set the Name or anything else because it says its undefined, I thought I was supposed to use the header to avoid that so I am wondering where I am going wrong.

BTW: I'm using MS Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: `#include "masterIncludes.h" //this has a bunch of std stuff like list and iostream ect.` - this is probably not as good an idea as you think it is.

Comment: O guess it has to be Morg::setName

Comment: You need a better book to learn from.

Answer (score 2):

Your .h is not secured. Here's a version with a guard, and proper includes, thanks to Daniel for poiting that out. Its a good behaviour to keep guardians and to include the library you're using for inside your declaration.

```
    #IFNDEF __MORG_H
    #DEFINE __MORG_H

    #include <string> 

    //-----------Morg-----------//
     class Morg{
      public:
       void setName( std::string morgName );
       void setType( char morgType );
       void setXcoord( int xLocation );
       void setYcoord( int yLocation );
       void moveMorg( int currDirection );
       void consume( Morg morg );
       void reproduce( char morgType );
       void setBounds( int upperBound );
       void setDirection( int currDirection );
       char getType();

   private:
       std::string Name;
       char Type;
       int yCoord;
       int xCoord;
       int bounds;
       int direction;
  };
  #ENDIF
```

And in your file .cpp, what you want to do is  :

```
//  #include "masterIncludes.h" //this is bad habit
 #include "Morg.h"


void Morg::setName( std::string morgName ){
    Name = morgName; //I get an error here it thinks name is undefined I've tried Morg::Name and     it stays undefined I dont know what im supposed to do.
}
std::string getName(){
    return Name;
}
void Morg::setType( char morgType ){

}
void Morg::setXcoord( int xLocation ){

}
void Morg::setYcoord( int yLocation ){

}
void Morg::moveMorg( int currDirection ){

}
void Morg::consume( Morg morg ){

}
void Morg::reproduce( char morgType ){

}
void Morg::setBounds( int upperBound ){

}
void Morg::setDirection( int currDirection ){

}
char Morg::getType(){

}
```

That should do the trick !

Comment: This did not work for me, this I appreciate the tip for guards I just hadn't really gotten there yet since I just wanted to get basic functionality working.  I still cant get it to understand which Name I am referring to.

Comment: give me the full message from your compiler please @beginnerBinx

Answer (score 0):

The name of the function definition shold be

```
void Morg::setName( std::string morgName ){ Name = morgName; }
std::string Morg::getName(){return Name;}
void Morg::setType( char morgType ){}
void Morg::setXcoord( int xLocation ){}
void Morg::setYcoord( int yLocation ){}
void Morg::moveMorg( int currDirection ){}
```

etc. etc.

This is needed being the function part of the `Morg` class, and not top-level function as they will be if not name-qualified.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue.  I knew it was something easy I just couldnt find it when I was googling for it for some reason.